# Transforming dataframe based on the column data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to transform the my dataframe as below. I want to do it using the loop as I will not know how many years of data I will have in real-time data, this is just a sample
[image]

data :

```
Year,Country,state,sex,dist,population
2019,IND,AP,F,EG,123
2019,IND,AP,F,WG,123
2019,IND,AP,F,VZA,96
2019,IND,AP,F,BZA,172
2019,IND,AP,M,EG,101
2019,IND,AP,M,WG,174
2019,IND,AP,M,VZA,86
2019,IND,AP,M,BZA,129
2019,IND,UP,F,A,107
2019,IND,UP,F,B,112
2019,IND,UP,M,C,165
2019,IND,UP,M,D,99
2020,IND,AP,F,EG,77
2020,IND,AP,F,WG,123
2020,IND,AP,F,VZA,116
2020,IND,AP,F,BZA,79
2020,IND,AP,M,EG,110
2020,IND,AP,M,WG,144
2020,IND,AP,M,VZA,93
2020,IND,AP,M,BZA,132
2020,IND,UP,F,A,150
2020,IND,UP,F,B,100
```

CODE :

```
serial=df.Year.unique()
global a
a=[]

for i in range(len(serial)):
  
    globals()['serial%s' % i]=df.loc[df.SERIAL==serial[i]]
    a.append('serial%s' % i)
    

k=pd.concat(a,axis=1,join='inner')
```

I have tried like this but it is not working because variable "a" is the list of strings, so `concat` is throwing `error` and not sure how to rename name column names[Year to 2020,2019]in the loop as pictured.
can you help to figure out

Comment: This operation is known as pivot: `k = df.pivot_table(index=['Country', 'state', 'sex', 'dist'], columns='Year', values='population').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()` (loop is not necessary this will work regardless of number of years.)

Comment: Thank you so much Henry Ecker for the simple and easy solution